# DOMPXPATH how to get the text before and after a br tag

Tags: php, html, domxpath

I would like to know how to get contents that are before and after a br tag. Here is the content of my html file.

```
<table class="resultTable">

    <tr>
       <th colspan="2">
           <span style="float:left;"><h3>Curcon</h3></span>
           <span style="float:right;"><small><img src="/if/stars/0.gif" alt="0" /> 
            <a href="/reviews/read?customerID=739">Review</a></small></span>
      </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
       <td width="590">
            Adres: Industrieterrein Seru Loraweg 30B</span>
            <br/>
            Telefoon: (599-9) 736-7212<br/>Fax: (599-9) 736-7207
            <br/>Mobiele telefoon: (599-9) 513-1792<br/> 
      </td>
      <td valign="top" rowspan="2" class="resultslogo">
            <img src="" />
     </td>       
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Categorie&euml
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="moreinfo" colspan="2">

</tr>
</table>
```

And here the php code i have. So far i can retrieve the contacts information in the second row. However i would like to get them separably. The address, then the phone, and finally the fax.

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query('//table[@class="resultTable"]') as $div) {

 $trs = $div->getElementsByTagName("tr");
 $trs->item(1)->getElementsByTagName("td")->item(0)->nodeValue;

}
```

Comment: That HTML looks a bit broken.

Answer (score 0):

you are saying to get the address, phone and fax separately also you are putting all these together into a single 
I'll suggest you to place them separately in separate  so that you can get the data easily.

Comment: I do not have control over the html. I got it via file_get_contents(), so i cant modify the html